# Yii module init method not called

Tags: yii

From module A, I am calling renderPartial on another module B, but B module's init() method is not getting called,however the view is rendered without styles since the styles are defined in init method as Module B's assets. What could be reason ?

**Call from a partial view from module A**

```
$this->renderPartial('application.modules.B.views.B._view',array(), false , true);
```

Yii - 1.1.14

Using custom client script - NLSClientScript from yii-extension version 5
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript/

Comment: please also post the init method of module B.

Comment: There are bunch of registerCss and registerScript calls inside both module's init methods. In module A init(), also setImports is called and module B's models are added as dependencies. But here, it is not going to even first line of Module B init() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**renderPartial** won't make an instance of Module **B**,

it simply renders that view file only,

so the class functions won't get fired,

if you want those scripts available, you may want to consider putting them in a static function so it will be accessible from elsewere.

Comment: @tinybite, you are right, i started doing getModule() instead of making them static and now init() method is getting called.

Comment: glad could help, and it's tinybyte not bite ;)